# How do I choose between Xml serialization, DataContractSerializer and LINQ to XML for serializing a tree of simple objects?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, datacontractserializer

I need to serialize a tree of simple objects as XML to/from a file – the world has changed since I last had to do this…

(I don’t care about the schema of the XML provided a support person can understand the file if needed)

So what are the trade off to consider when choosing between the different “easy xml” APIs in .net?

Comment: check out the Listing 3,4 Points. Here they define the customized  methods :  http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I have come to think about the options:

**LINQ to XML** – full control over the XML and the design of the objects, the most code of any of the 3 options.

**DataContractSerializer** – little or no control over the XML, can cope with most objects

**XmlSerializer** – full control over the XML, but you must design the objects in a way that Xml Serialization likes.

Comment: Another aspect is that `XmlSerializer` is pretty much frozen - there will likely be no new development, and only the most critical bug fixes.

Answer (score 3):

`DataContractSerializer` doesn't necessarily emit "typical" xml, and you don't have much control over the output. It does, however, support full-graphs if you need. If you want xml, and don't need full-graphs, I would tend towards `XmlSerializer` - it'll avoid having to write any code for manually traversing the data (ala `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`), yet give you control.

One caveat: `XmlSerializer` places demands on your type (public, public parameterless constructor, limited to public members, no serialization callbacks, etc). They are usually not a problem.

But then, I'd probably be writing binary instead of xml anyway ;p (just not with `BinaryFormatter`, which has.... kinks).

Comment: Thanks, The XmlSerializer still seems to have issues with immutable objects, but it is what I have always used in the past.  The data is "config data" with a custom editor and is so small that there is no need to use binary.